# Regex to Match Passed Function/Method Parameters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've had a good look around for a question that asked this before; alas, my search for a PHP `preg_match` search returned no results (maybe my searching skills fell short, I suppose <strike>justified</strike> considering it's a Regex question!).

Consider the text below:

> The quick `__("brown ")` fox jumps `__('over the')` lazy `__("dog")`

Now currently I need to 'scan' for the given method `__('')` above, whereas it could include the spacing and different quotations (`'`|`"`). My best attempt after numerous 'iterations':

`(__\("(.*?)"\))|(__\('(.*?)'\))`

Or at its simplest form:

`__\((.*?)\)`

To break this down:

- Anything that starts with `__`
- Escaped `(` and quotation mark `"` or `'`. Thus, `\(\"`
- `(.*?)` Non-greedy match of all characters
- Escaped closing `"` and last bracket.
- `|` between the two expressions match either/or.

However, this only gets partial matches, and spaces are throwing off the search entirely. Apologies if this has been asked before, please link me if so!

Tester Link for the pattern provided above:

[**PHP** Live Regex Test Tool](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/exC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the searched method string uses single quotes it will end up in another capture group than if it has double quotes. So in fact, your regular expression works (except for the spaces, see further down), but you'd have to look at a different index in your result array:

```
$input = 'The quick __("brown ") fox jumps __(\'over the\') lazy __("dog")';

// using your regular expression:
$res = preg_match_all("/(__\(\"(.*?)\"\))|(__\('(.*?)'\))/", $input, $matches);

print_r ($matches);
```

Note that you need `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match` to get all matches.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => __("brown ")
            [1] => __('over the')
            [2] => __("dog")
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => __("brown ")
            [1] => 
            [2] => __("dog")
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => brown 
            [1] => 
            [2] => dog
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => __('over the')
            [2] => 
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => over the
            [2] => 
        )
)
```

So, the result array has 5 elements, the first one representing the complete match, and all the others correspond to the 4 capture groups you have in your regular expression. As the capture groups for single quotes are not those of the double quotes, you'll find the matches at different places.

To *"solve"* this, you could use a back reference in your regular expression, which would look back to see which was the opening quote (single or double) and require the same to be repeated at the end:

```
$res = preg_match_all("/__\(([\"'])(.*?)\\1\)/", $input, $matches);
```

Note the back reference `\1` (the backslash had to be escaped with another one). This refers back to the first capture group, where we have `["']` (again an escape was necessary) to match both kinds of quotes.

You also wanted to deal with spaces. On your [PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/exC) you used a test string that had such spaces between the brackets and quotes. To deal with these so they still match the method strings correctly, the regular expression should get two additional `\s*`:

```
$res = preg_match_all("/__\(\s*([\"'])(.*?)\\1\s*\)/", $input, $matches);
```

Now the output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => __("brown ")
            [1] => __('over the')
            [2] => __("dog")
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "
            [1] => '
            [2] => "
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => brown 
            [1] => over the
            [2] => dog
        )
)
```

... and the text captured by the groups is now nicely arranged.

See this code run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/514476) and [PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/exG).

Comment: Good afternoon @trincot; I must say after numerous tests today - I can confirm, this has worked really nicely for me. It's importantly covered escaping issues which I didn't even cover in the question; thank you for the nicely constructed answer too!

Answer (score 1):

When working with stuff like this, don't forget about escaping:

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>

The quick __("brown ") fox jumps __(  'over the'  ) lazy __("dog").
And __("everyone says \"hi\"").

<?php

$content = ob_get_clean();

$re = <<<RE
    /__ \(
        \s*
        " ( (?: \\\\. | [^"])+ ) "
        |
        ' ( (?: \\\\. | [^'])+ ) '
        \s*
    \)
    /x
RE;

preg_match_all($re, $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach($matches as $match)
    echo end($match), "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
 (__(\('[^']+'\)|\("[^"]+"\)))
```

Instead of the non greedy `.`, use any char but the quotes `[^']` or `[^"]`

Answer (score 0):

Enclose double and single quotes with square brackets as a character class:

```
$str = 'The quick __( "brown ") fox jumps __(\'over the\') lazy __("dog")';

preg_match_all("/__\(\s*([\"']).*?\\1\s*\)/ium", $str, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($matches[0]);

// the output:
array (size=3)
    0 => string '__( "brown ")' 
    1 => string '__('over the')'
    2 => string '__("dog")'
```

And here is example with the same solution on *phpliveregex.com*: 
 http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/exF
(section `preg_match_all`)

Comment: This would allow matching `__('I mix quotes")`.

Comment: @trincot, I've tried backreference `\1`, but it doesn't work for me, seemed oddly

Comment: It works for me. I will check on different PHP versions.... You did not BTW forget to escape the backslash in `\1`?

Comment: I have php 5.5.11, but also doesn't work on `http://www.phpfiddle.org/`. Actually, that was getting me nervous, cause I was relying on backreference approach

Comment: @trincot, man, how can I miss it? sure, you were right, it's about escaping `\\1`. Thanks and apologies

Comment: I would remove the `*` in the quotes group though.

Comment: agree to this, it remained from the early test. I've removed it. Thanks